# Monitor/view response codes of HTTPS traffic (e.g. port 443)?

Tags: linux, linux-networking

Is it possible to monitor/view the response codes of traffic to a server with HTTPS? I can use ngrep or tcpdump to view HTTP (port 80) but this won't work for HTTPS (port 443) requests - they simply don't show up.

For example, I'd like to test if web pages that googlebot is requesting are responding with 500 error codes, so that I can track down problems with googlebot not being able to access my pages.

I'm thinking maybe something like WireShark could do it, but I have no idea where to begin with a tool like that, and I'm not sure it can see the response codes since HTTPS is encrypted?

Comment: When a server is still capable of sending an error response (rather than not responding at all) it will also be able to log that error response - so check the server logs rather than sniffing network traffic and configure monitoring and alerting to know if the server is still up

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate of 1015957 - please don't ask variants of the same question twice - rather add both details to 1